# How can I defend my position of being against homosexuality in front of unbelievers?

Tags: homosexuality

I am a high school student who stands fervently against homosexuality. I have remained quiet about my belief so far, but now it has been coming up in class as a topic that should be supported, and those against homosexuality have been discussed as bigoted and wrongly biased.

I want to stand up for my position, and I'm completely willing to risk my reputation in the process, but I just don't know what to say if I'm asked *why* I stand against homosexuality. The only reason I have at the moment is that the Bible is against homosexuality. That is sufficient for me, but obviously non-Christians, who don't believe in the validity of the Bible, want more reasons or at least more definite reasons.

What should I say if a non-Christian asks me why I'm against homosexuality?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the Site Tour. For some tips on asking good questions here, see: [What makes a good focused question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question). Although this is a noble and worthwhile pursuit, these types of questions are considered off-topic on this site. Perhaps you could ask how a specific denomination or tradition of Christianity views homosexuality and perhaps the defense for their position.

Comment: @LoganBaxter Perhaps this is an inappropriate question for this site. Where would be a good place to ask this question?

Comment: A question of this magnitude cannot be adequately answered by people who don't know you, your classmates, or the city you live in!  Talking to the pastor of your church or someone you trust who has faced a similar experience may be your best bet. I wish you the best of luck in your situation however!

Comment: The simplest approach is "love the sinner but detest the sin" but @LoganBaxter has the right of it: seek counsel with your pastor.

Comment: Jehovah's Witnesses often have to explain the Bible's view of homosexuality to people they meet in the ministry. When I was in high school, [this article on jw.org](https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/teenagers/ask/is-homosexuality-wrong/) taught me how to explain my beliefs clearly and peacefully.

Comment: Acceptance of homosexuality, pedophilia, and other abnormal sexual perversions (in the Biblical view) are the symptom of a societal decline into moral subjectivity: this is concern enough for *anyone,* since it means that potentially any other thing could become moral some day (e.g. pedophilia). If this doesn't concern anyone, regardless of religious conviction, we have bigger problems than 'offending someone's feelings.'

Comment: @user370 I know how it feels to be in this situation. It don't matter what you say. I had this same discussion with someone who is a homosexual, qnd after showing him my reasoning (religion, grossed out by it, disease, etc.) He literally told me "I am will enjoy burning in Hell with you, you m#%@#$-f@$%## bigit!" They just wanna see you stumble. And, when you stay true, they just cuss you out and walk off. Also, if you give sound reasoning, get ready for *all* of their friends to insult you, for at least 10 minutes straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of us is without sin totally.
With the transgender nonsense, we can refer to Genesis 1:27.

27. So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them.

Sodom and Gomorrah were destroyed because of their wickedness in Genesis 18-19.

We can argue that the Greek and Roman Empires fell because of their wickedness.

Sadly, we're seeing the same behavior rampant today.

As Christians, we need to show mercy, but not to condone what God clearly states as harmful behavior. We shouldn't "candy coat" bad behavior. But we need to show tact when pointing out flaws. We need to examine ourselves for hypocrisy and pray for our own repentance before approaching the others.

Luke 15:7 states:
7. I tell you that in the same way there will be more rejoicing in heaven over one sinner who repents than over ninety-nine righteous persons who do not need to repent.

1 Peter 4:7-9 reinforces this:
7. The end of all things is near. Therefore be clear minded and self-controlled so that you can pray.
8. Above all, love each other deeply, because love covers over a multitude of sins.
9. Offer hospitality to one another without grumbling.

Contrast the fruit of the Spirit with worldly behavior. Colossians 3 & Galatians 5 are good chapters for this. There are other references, too.

I applaud your stance. 
Keep doing what is simply right in the eyes of God & pressing closer to God and He will reward you.

Stay in the Word by reading your Bible often. When you aren't sure about a decision you should take, consult the Bible. There are online studies you can read as long as it is a godly source.

Comment: Gender dysphoria is not nonsense, and Christians need to respond with care and empathy.

Comment: @curiousdannii possibly not, but the current hubub surrounding transgendersism is clearly nonsensical.  It's either mountain or a molehill, it can't be both.

Answer (score 2):

It is against the law, here in the UK, to make remarks that would be considered 'homophobic' in a public place and, in certain circumstances, in private.

I prefer, myself, to state matters in a fundamental way, rather than make personal remarks. For example, I prefer to state that God made male and female, and God did so with a purpose.

It was God who created humanity and it was God who made the way that humanity is propagated. And he made it all for a purpose.

The ultimate purpose of God becomes clear in Christ and in the Church, the Body and Bride of Christ.

I find it best to speak of these matters in this way.

Answer (score 1):

There are several books that can help.  I haven't read any of 'em but I see them advertised a lot on the National Catholic Register, Gilbert! Magazine and various flyers I get from publishers of finer Catholic media.

1. Making Gay Okay: How Rationalizing Homosexual Behavior is Changing Everything by Robert R. Reilly

   > Well-written, timely and insightful work that casts light on the homosexual agenda
   >   https://www.catholiccompany.com/making-gay-okay-rationalizing-homosexual-behavior-changing-everything-i113020/?sli=1007029
2. Why I Don't Call Myself Gay: How I Reclaimed My Sexual Reality and Found Peace by Daniel Mattson

   > Part memoir, part philosophy about reality, and part a practical guide for living chastely, Mattson draws lessons from his own fight for chastity, sharing wisdom from his own failures and successes

Beyond that it's good to ponder what Pope Francis meant when he said "who am I to Judge" in reference to a hypothetical gay man trying to live a good life.

If you need practice, get some reputation on this site by answering some questions and argue with other Christians in the Chatroom of this website, there's plenty of us who could go either way when it comes to homosexuality.

The "how" part of "how can I defend my position" is simple, just state your feelings.  Remember, (and this is what I learned from Christian Marriage Encounter) feelings are never wrong.  Obviously they're not always right either, but if you're in an emotionally charged debate and you say

> I feel that homosexuality harms a person's soul.

What is the argument against that?  And that's what the problem is - the reason for disliking homosexuality is what it does to the person caught up in the lifestyle (and their families).  I feel it's natural to be angry with it, the same as it's natural to be angry with anything that helps ones vices destroy their chances of happiness (alcohol, kleptomania, too much money).

Don't give up, but don't give in to the temptation to get over emotional when arguing against homosexuality.  Don't let someone telling you it's a hate crime stop you. If it's a hate crime to state your feelings then you have the obligation to fight on both fronts, but your compassion should be with the homosexuals, not the bureaucrats.

Comment: I like the first part of this answer. I'd like to see quotes from those sources, but as you said, you haven't read them.